# Chrome: switch tabs with exactly one key?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to switch tabs using exactly one keystroke in Chrome? I've tried the [Shortcut Manager extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf), but it doesn't disable the shortcuts while in text fields, which makes it impossible (or, at least, impractical) to use a single keystroke to switch tabs.

Comment: Wouldn't assigning only one key cause an interference while typing. By default Ctrl + <number> let's you switch to a tab. If only <number> was responsible for switching tabs then no one would be able to type a number to a text box in Chrome. Unless you want the shortcuts to only work when you are not using text boxes in web pages; which is not how Chrome currently works.

Comment: Nope. The plugins that I use in Safari and Firefox simply ignore the keystroke if you're in a text field. And can you be more specific by “not how Chrome currently works”? Is there any reason plugins couldn't simply check the `originalTarget` of the key press event to determine if it's an input?

Comment: What I meant by 'not how Chrome currently works' was that the default keyboard shortcuts work even while I'm in a text box. So the chance that you would be able to set shortcuts, based on how chrome default shortcuts worked looked slim. A baseless presumption!!! Hopefully you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Vimium](http://vimium.github.com/) in Chrome. It enables vim-like keyboard shortcuts. Default for switching tab is uppercase <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> (so you may count this as two key strokes, but I do think it should be possible to remap). As vim uses the concept of edit/visual/insert mode it should not interfere when you are in text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try Autohotkey. The script will go something like this--

```
z::
shifttab
return
```